# One of multiple Tasks acquires a lock in Mutex much longer than other Tasks do

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library, mutex

**SITUATION**

Currently in my project I have 3 `Workers` that have a working loop inside, and one `CommonWork` class object, which contains `Work` methods (*DoFirstTask, DoSecondTask, DoThirdTask*) that `Workers` can call. Each `Work` method must be executed mutually exclusively in respect to each other method. Each of methods spawn more nested `Tasks` that are waited until they are finished.

**PROBLEM**

When all 3 `Workers` are started, 2 `Workers` perform somewhat at the same speed, but 3rd `Worker` is lagging behind **or** 1st `Worker` is super-fast, 2nd a bit slower and 3rd is very slow, it depends on real world.

**BIZARRENESS**

When only 2 `Workers` are working, they share the work nicely too, and perform at the same speed.

What's more interesting, that even 3rd `Worker` calls fewer number of `CommonWork` methods, and has the potential to perform more ***loop*** cycles, it does not. I tried to simulate that in the code below with condition:

```
if (Task.CurrentId.Value < 3)
```

When debugging, I found out, that 3rd `Worker` was waiting on acquiring a lock on a `Mutex` substantially longer than other `Workers`. Sometimes, other two `Workers` just work interchangingly, and the 3rd keeps waiting on `Mutex.WaitOne()`; I guess, without really entering it, because other `Workers` have no problem in acquiring that lock!

**WHAT I TRIED ALREADY**

I tried starting `Worker` `Tasks` as `TaskCreateOptions.LongRunning`, but nothing changed. I also tried making *nested* `Tasks` to be *child* `Tasks` by specifying `TaskCreateOpions.AttachedToParent`, thinking it might be related to *local queues* and scheduling, but apparently it is not.

**SIMPLIFIED CODE**

Below is the simplified code of my real-world application. Sad to say, I could not reproduce this situation in this simple example:

```
class Program
{
    public class CommonWork
    {
        private Mutex _mutex;
        public CommonWork() { this._mutex = new Mutex(false); }    
        private void Lock() { this._mutex.WaitOne(); }    
        private void Unlock() { this._mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }

        public void DoFirstTask(int taskId)
        {
            this.Lock();
            try
            {
                // imitating sync work from 3rd Party lib, that I need to make async
                var t = Task.Run(() => { 
                    Thread.Sleep(500); // sync work
                });
                ... // doing some work here
                t.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: DoFirstTask - complete", taskId);    
            }
            finally { this.Unlock(); }
        }

        public void DoSecondTask(int taskId)
        {
            this.Lock();
            try
            {
                // imitating sync work from 3rd Party lib, that I need to make async
                var t = Task.Run(() => { 
                    Thread.Sleep(500); // sync work
                });
                ... // doing some work here
                t.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: DoSecondTask - complete", taskId);
            }
            finally { this.Unlock(); }
        }

        public void DoThirdTask(int taskId)
        {
            this.Lock();
            try
            {
                // imitating sync work from 3rd Party lib, that I need to make async
                var t = Task.Run(() => { 
                    Thread.Sleep(500); // sync work
                });
                ... // doing some work here
                t.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Task {0}: DoThirdTask - complete", taskId);
            }
            finally { this.Unlock(); }
        }
    }

    // Worker class

    public class Worker
    {
        private  CommonWork CommonWork { get; set; }
        public Worker(CommonWork commonWork)
        { this.CommonWork = commonWork; }

        private void Loop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                this.CommonWork.DoFirstTask(Task.CurrentId.Value);
                if (Task.CurrentId.Value < 3)
                {
                    this.CommonWork.DoSecondTask(Task.CurrentId.Value);
                    this.CommonWork.DoThirdTask(Task.CurrentId.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        public Task Start()
        {
            return Task.Run(() => this.Loop());
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var work = new CommonWork();
        var client1 = new Worker(work);
        var client2 = new Worker(work);
        var client3 = new Worker(work);
        client1.Start();
        client2.Start();
        client3.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
} // end of Program
```

Comment: Don't use `Task.Run` to get a ThreadPool thread and then `Wait` to block on it.

Comment: @I3arnon, not sure, what you mean. I need those `Tasks` to be waited for before `Worker` can proceed to next task=method. Everything is fine with that.

Comment: You don't need those tasks at all, because you wasting a thread waiting for them to complete. Simply have the thread execute the work inside the task.

Comment: @I3arnon, I know what you mean, but I need them. Check the more specific code now.

Comment: My comments still stand. If you have `async` work then make the `DoXTask` method `async` as well, and use `SemphoreSlim` instead of a `Mutex`.

Comment: @I3arnon, making them `async` will just make me `Wait` on `Task` in method `Loop` - the order of `Do Tasks` must remain as it is. You mean `new SemaphoreSlim(1)`? I already tried changing `Mutex` to `Monitor`, as it is better in this scenario (I don't need Interprocess-locking). But then, with `Monitor`, I don't make a 3rd `Worker` acquire a lock at all!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67332/discussion-between-gabrielius-and-i3arnon).

Comment: How many cores do you actually have? If you only have two real cores (i.e. not including Hyperthread cores), then I'd expect exactly the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I have 4 real cores. The problem, is that this sample app performs well (I still cannot reproduce the error), it does not wait on `Mutex` too long, and grants each `Worker` time to perform his task just on time.

Comment: Have you considered not reinventing the wheel, and just using the normal `lock` statement instead of a `Mutex` object? The former is defined to use a round-robin scheduling mechanism, while `Mutex` is not. From the docs for the native mutex object, on which `Mutex` is based: "If more than one thread is waiting on a mutex, a waiting thread is selected. **Do not assume a first-in, first-out (FIFO) order**". In other words, it's normal for two threads to go back and forth owning a mutex, while a third gets left out.

Comment: @I3arnon, place an answer that using `new SempahoreSlim(1)` is a solution and I will accept it as an answer. @PeterDuniho, tried exchanging `Mutex` with an ordinary `lock` but `Thread Scheduling` in my particular case was **not** *round-robin* - just checked it out (same with `Monitor.Enter(obj)`). However, `SemaphoreSlim` scheduled threads in a `FIFO` way. So, it still leaves me in a mystery.

Comment: @Gabrielius This question is too long for me to get into. You can self-answer it if you like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `new SempahoreSlim(1)` instead of `Mutex` (or simple `lock`, or `Monitor`). Only using `SemaphoreSlim` made `Thread Scheduling` to be *round-robin*, and therefore did not make some Threads/Tasks "special" in respect to other threads. Thanks I3arnon.

If someone could comment why it is so, I would appreciate it.